# SQLite ordering date

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to order date from early to late with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM event where event_date >= strftime('%d/%m/%Y','now') ORDER BY event_date ASC;
```

However it doesn't seem to fully work (see image). The 3rd row returns a date 30/12/2016 which is later than the 4th row which is 31/05/2016.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should read [this](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and [this](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). TLDR: those aren't dates from SQLite's POV, they're text, and they're being ordered as text.

Comment: Your `event_date` is probably a sting, not a datetime data field. Fix your schema.

Comment: Ah yes, read the documentation!

Comment: My dates are stored as DATE not strings by the way.

Comment: If you read the docs I linked, you'll see "SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values" - so they are definitely not stored as DATE.

Comment: SQLite basically ignores the data-type you specify. You can store text in an INTEGER column if you like. You can specify a data-type of "foobar" and the create table statement will succeed.

Comment: Okay so the result i'm seeing is just random and coincidentally has the first two elements sorted?

Comment: No, it's not random: they are sorted as text: "26", "27", "30", "31".

Comment: Oh right I need them sorted by month and year though.

Answer (score -1):

Your `event_date` field is likely a `VARCHAR` type, so it orders by `2` and `3`, then by `6`, `7` etc.

A quick fix would be to change your date notation to YYYYMMDD (year, month, day), because that *is* sort-able even as a string.

Comment: There is no DATE data-type in SQLite. You just use YMD format (as you suggest), or integers (UNIX time), or floating point number of days since 4714 B.C. (for some reason) - all sortable as-is.

Comment: Didn't know, thanks. And had to look up that strange 4714 BC: "The Julian Period is a chronological interval of 7980 years beginning 4713 BC." ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day))